# R: Row and column mean produces the same matrix as used for input

Tags: r, mean

I randomly tried some commands in R and came across this one:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)
#[,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
apply(m, c(1,2), mean)
#[,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
```

According to the documentation:

> c(1, 2) indicates rows and columns

Why would this produce the same matrix as used as input?

Comment: Applying the mean over 2 dimensions of a 2-dimensional object does result in the same object. Here, the mean function is applied four times (for each single value).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it calculates the mean for each value i.e. mean(1) = 1, mean(3) = 3 etc? @SvenHohenstein

Comment: Exactly. Try with `1` or `2` instead of `c(1,  2)` and see what happens.